# Kubernetes Helm Chart If Condition Check

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-templates, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to add if great than condition in Helm chart. it is throwing error.

I have defined value in values.yaml and using that value in deployment.yaml for condition.

**values.yaml**

```
replicaCount: 2
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
rollingUpdate:
  maxSurge: 1
  {{ if gt .Values.replicaCount 2}}
  maxUnavailable: 0
  {{ else }}
  maxUnavailable: 1
  {{ end }}
```

I am using helm dry run option to check result. getting error

```
Error: render error in "hello-world/templates/deployment.yaml": template: hello-world/templates/deployment.yaml:16:12: executing "hello-world/templates/deployment.yaml" at <gt .Values.replicaCo...>: error calling gt: incompatible types for comparison
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Can u help me to do type casting ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using float number in comparison instead:

**deployment.yaml**

```
rollingUpdate:
  maxSurge: 1
  {{ if gt .Values.replicaCount 2.0}}
  maxUnavailable: 0
  {{ else }}
  maxUnavailable: 1
  {{ end }}
```

Helm (along with underlying Golang templates and Yaml) can be weird sometimes.

---

Also, note that sometimes you need to typecast values in your yaml configs (e.g. port numbers).

Example:

```
...
ports:
- containerPort: !!int {{ .Values.containers.app.port }}
...
```

More about Yaml type casting: https://github.com/yaml/YAML2/wiki/Type-casting

Comment: I am trying with type casting option . it is not working. it is throwing error.{{- if gt !!int {{ .Values.replicaCount }} 1}}. how to type cast ?

Comment: You can also try typecasting not by yaml but by Go templates: `containerPort: {{ .Values.replicaCount | int }}`

Comment: What is the "-" is {{- if .Values.enable}} .. .. {{- end }} referred as?

Comment: @Pasha it is about controlling whitespace. Please see: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#controlling-whitespace